# Does quasiconvexity imply weak lower semicontinuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, weak-topology

Let $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ be the usual Sobolev space, $f(x,\eta,\xi)$ a continuous function, $1<p<\infty$, $\Omega$ an open and bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$, and $F: W^{1,p}(\Omega) \longrightarrow \mathbb{ \bar R}$ defined as $$F(u)=\int_\Omega f(x,u(x),\nabla u(x)) \, dx.$$
It is known that, if

- $f$ is convex in $\xi$ and
- $f(x,\eta,\xi) \geq \alpha(x)+\beta|\eta|^p+\langle \gamma(x), \xi \rangle$ for some $\alpha \in L^1, \,\beta \in \mathbb R$ and $\gamma \in L^{p'}$,

then $F$ is weak lower semicontinuous.

My question is: is this theorem true also for $f$ quasiconvex instead of convex with respect to $\xi$ only?

Comment: It seems like $X$ is not an arbitrary Banach space but maybe a Sobolev space or some other function space. This might be important because the topology sometimes matters for these questions.

Comment: Also, could you provide a sketch of the proof for the case that $f$ is convex in $\xi$? Where does it go wrong if you use that $f$ is quasiconvex instead?

Comment: @harfe thank you, it's a Sobolev space, in particular $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$

Comment: What is the range of $p$ here? $[1,\infty)$ or $p = \infty$?

Comment: @CheeHan sorry, $p \in (1, \infty)$